# How to enable user to Sync app directory from external memory to their Dropbox account?

Tags: android, dropbox, synchronization

My app creates a directory containing database and table to save data in external memory of mobile. I want to enable user to link this app directory with their personal Dropbox which can sync data over 3G or Wi-Fi obviously with dropbox whenever any changes is made in database of app. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: This is a pretty generic question, but the basic idea is that Dropbox offers an API you can use to sync files to and from user accounts: https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: thanks for this link Greg..i can enable user to link to their dropbox account through app and create a folder on dropbox. Now, i want to sync the whole folder and its content from mobile device to dropbox in created folder, which i am not able to do so..Any help please?